# How to fill all cell of the calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to fill all height of the cell of the calendar (in the month view), this is what I did:

```
var event =
{
     'id': content.id,
     'start': content.start,
     'end': content.end,
     'allDay': true,
     'color': '#ff0000'
};
```

the problem's that I cannot see the cell of the calendar all filled, but I see only a rectangle. I need for example all the cell filled as red, in my example in the month view. Is it possible?

And also, is possible propagate the event to another cell?

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed dayRender property ,but how can I set the color of specific date?

Comment: @inetphantom I'm using javascript, I need to call `dayrender` after initalization, and set color of specific date.